# Git. Синхронизация локального репозитория с удаленным

Tags: git

Для распостранения кода используем Git.

Если необходима установка софта заказчику - делается `git clone` мастер ветки на его сервере.

Если нужно обновить софт - `git pull`. Но с `git pull` обнаружилась одна особенность (понятно что обнаружилась для меня :) ) - он тянет изменения если на сервере прокрутился коммит, а если мы в локальном репозитории прибьем парочку файлов но комиты на сервере и локально совпадают то он их не востановит. Есть ли возможность так сказать актуализировать репозиторий, тоесть проверить совпадает ли количество и содержание файлов локально и на сервере и в случае обнаружения недостачи восполнить ее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняйте в директории репозитория:

```
git checkout -- ./ && git pull
```

Первая команда восстановит всё удалённое/изменённое, вторая вольёт изменения с сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы удаляете файл из папки проекта, то он все равно останется в **локальном** репозитории.

Чтобы его восстановить, нужно сделать `git checkout -- filename`

Comment: спасибо за ответ но вы мне предлагаете скальпель и я его возьму себе на вооружение но следующий ответ более общий и в конкретнном случае подходит больше (те кто будут на сервере заказчика пытатся востановить пропавшие файлы вряд ли будут знать их имена  )

Comment: @totorro `git status` покажет все незафиксированные изменения (в том числе удаленные файлы с именами), если нужно будет откатить какой-то отдельный файл.